# Double elements in list from N to N, code gives false

Tags: prolog

I have as input a list of numbers and I have to generate a new list with the elements from N to N doubled. For example:

```
?-double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],2,L). returns L=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7] (in this case N=2)

?-double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],3,L). returns L=[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7] (in this case N=3)
```

I have come up with the following code:

```
double(List, N, L) :- double(List, N, 1, L).

double([], N, Index, L).

double([H|T], N, Index, [H,H|L]) :-
    Index =:= N,
    double(T,N,1,L).

double([H|T], N, Index, [H|L]) :-
    Index =\= N,
    newIndex is Index + 1,
    double(T,N,newIndex,L).
```

Unfortunately, my code returns false. Can you guys point out the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos in your code:

1. In the base case, replace `L` with `[]`.
2. In the second recursive clause, replace `newIndex` with `NewIndex`.

I.e. When the input list is empty (or when reaching the end of the list after processing its elements), the output list will be also the empty list. Variables in Prolog start with an underscore or an upper case letter.